# Can't get Cython to work when compiling for C++

Tags: c++, compilation, cython

I'm trying do a simple example to cythonize a c++ Test class. I can't get it to work, why?

Here is my code, very basic:

**mytest.h:**

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(unsigned test = 0);

    void print();
private:
    unsigned m_test;
```

};

**mytest.cpp:**

```
#include "mytest.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Test::Test(unsigned test)
: m_test(test)
{
  cout << "Test::Test" << endl;
}
void Test::print()
{
  cout << "print:" << m_test << endl;
}
```

For the Cython part, I have, **test.pyx**:

```
cdef extern from "mytest.h":
  cdef cppclass Test:
    Test(unsigned int) except +
    void print()

cdef class pyTest:
  cdef Test* thisptr
    def __cinit__(self, unsigned test):
    self.thisptr = new Test(test)
  def __dealloc__(self):
    del self.thisptr
```

And i compile with:

```
cython --cplus test.pyx
```

... And get a ton of error messages, like "Empty declarator":

```
> Error compiling Cython file:
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
> cdef extern from "mytest.h":
>         cdef cppclass Test:
>                 Test(unsigned int) except +
>                 void print()
>       ^
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>  
> test.pyx:4:7: Empty declarator
> 
> Error compiling Cython file:
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
> cdef extern from "mytest.h":
>         cdef cppclass Test:
>                 Test(unsigned int) except +
>                 void print()
>       ^
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> test.pyx:4:7: Syntax error in C variable declaration
```

What am I not seeing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been where you are few weeks ago. Since I am a new user of Cython as well, I can't say for sure, but giving following advice.

You may want to put following lines at the top of your .pyx file (very easy to ignore in Cython tutorial)

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = mytest.cpp.
```

And for compile command, you can use:

```
cython -a test.pyx --cplus
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunably I have the same results with distutils comments :(

Comment: @carmellose can you show more about your setups? I'm wondering if the bit-version could also cause such problem.

Comment: Hello, here are my settings: Cython version 0.19.2, Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Oct  7 2013, 11:56:55) and [GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem a few days ago. The issue is with the name of your print() method. For some reason, which I dont know exactly, cython doesn't like print(). If you change it to any other name, like printtest(). It will compile just fine.